# Where to ask if there is a public database about subsidiaries of companies?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119000/is-there-public-databases-about-subsidiaries-of-companies/119002#119002 on The Workplace, but apparently, it's not the right place and I'm off-topic.

> I have a list of suppliers I need to consolidate. I want to make
>   explicit that company A is a brand or a subsidiary of company B.
>
> I tried to see if Wikimedia or other public sources listed on Google
>   Dataset have a structured database with this information, with poor
>   results.
>
> I imagined a well-done JSON with nested relations between companies
>   would be easily available, as it is public information in most cases
>   and it will be useful to a lot of people, but I wasn't able to find
>   any. Maybe I didn't know where to look.
>
> **Is there such a database listing companies and their subsidiaries
>   and/or their brands? Is there any that are free? Is there any that are
>   open?**

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: And now, I can't delete it because I have an answer. What should I do?

Comment: Why would you want to delete it? If someone else wants to know they can see this question and its answer.

Comment: Should I ask the user who answered to withdraw their answer so I can delete my own question on The Workplace? 
Or should I wait for it to be deleted my moderators?
(I fell super bad :/ )

Comment: @RobertLongson My question was downvoted and voted for deletion as off-topic. Apparently, my question should have been posted on [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). So I'm polluting The Workplace's feed, right? or can I migrate my question to Open Data ?

Comment: You're better off just asking the question on the Open Data site rather than trying to get it migrated. If anyone else comes along and tries to ask a question similar to yours on the workspace they may notice yours and think again so your question might help someone else.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. I feel bad about not cleaning my error. Lesson learned. :/    
I'll edit my question in The Workplace to put a link to my question on Open Data. I guess that would be good practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your question belongs on [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com). According to their [help center](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about ...
>
> - where to [find any kind of open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request)
>
> ...
>
> ... then you're in the right place!

As indicated in the tag excerpt, please check [How a good data-request question should look](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look) before posting your question.