# Where can I ask questions related to gathering data sets?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My background is not in data science or marketing, but I have started a side project in which some data will be required, and I am not sure where to ask if the type of data set I seek already exists. Is there a stack exchange for that?

If you are curious, specifically what I want to know is if there already exists a data set containing, for at least 100 individual people, the photos in their facebook profiles (or their profiles at the time of collection). I want to use these some facebook profiles for a study and also potentially in marketing, but of course permission is required from each individual. It would be a pain to reach out to potentially thousands of people and get them to sign forms agreeing for their photos to be used, so I was wondering if there already exists such a dataset in which everyone represented in the data set already legally agreed for their photos to be used.

Comment: Maybe on OpenData.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332832/where-can-i-ask-for-a-dataset-of-ultrasound-images and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315298/where-to-ask-if-there-is-a-public-database-about-subsidiaries-of-companies and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218091